# TypeError: cannot read property 'execute' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My problem is the following: when compiling, I get the error that the property 'execute' is not defined. What I'm trying to do is open a file that is in another folder and dock it in the if, I was guided by the command handling documentation, I don't know if the error is in the other file which is called **'pong.js'**. I recently started, so I don't fully understand it. The main code is as follows:

**The Error** [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNHex.png)

**index.js file**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const keepAlive = require("./server")
const prefix = "!";

const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles){
  const command = require(`./src/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

// ======== Ready Log ========
client.on ("ready", () => {
    console.log('The Bot Is Ready!');
    client.user.setPresence({
      status: 'ONLINE', // Can Be ONLINE, DND, IDLE, INVISBLE
      activity: {
          name: '!tsc help',
          type: 'PLAYING', // Can Be WHATCHING, LISTENING
      }
  })
  }); 
 client.on('message', async message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
  let command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

  if (command === "ping"){
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args)
  }
})

const token = process.env.TOKEN;
keepAlive()
client.login(token);
```

**pong.js file**

```js
module.exports.run = {
  name: 'pong',
  description: "pong cmd",
  execute(message, args){
    message.reply("pong!")
  }
}
```

Comment: You named your command `'pong'` not ping

Comment: @Elitezen not working bro :(

Comment: `module.exports.run` should be `module.exports`, why are you nesting your export inside a `run` property?

Comment: @Elitezen working bro